# continuous integration with in house libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, libraries, dependency-management, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We have a project, say coresystem which uses a number of in house dependent libraries, all at different versions.

The build configuration for coresystem is setup to reference libraries with specific version numbers for example coresytem 2.3.4 uses libraries abc-version-1.2.3 and def-version-3.4.5.

These libraries are often changed during at the same time as coresystem. And not necessarily the same set of libraries change with each version of coresystem.

How do we handle continuous delivery in this case. Currently we are constantly having to change the build config of coresystem.

Comment: i have been trying to think of a solution that is not stupid for months now and can't work out how to do it other than doing the libraries manual

Comment: which build system are you using? something like gradle, sbt, bazel etc

Comment: I'm using Maven or MSBuild, but this question relates to any build system. Its a generic issue to software dev I am finding.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables as parameters that you can pass in to the build system instead of putting them into the config is going to give you what you would like to achieve here. Depending on the build system you are using there are different ways to pass in parameters like this.

For example Gitlab CI/CD uses this:

https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#custom-environment-variables